# time.sleep is not working for me as the rolling command keep occuring

Tags: python

Rolling keeps on ptinting on my screen with two numbers apprearing from min and max.

I tried adding print("End") but the command keeps looping.

```
if name == "Name":
    pwd= input ("Enter Password")
    if pwd == 'password':
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Incorrect login, checkdetails and try again")

else:
    print("Incorrect Username")


min = 1
max = 6
score =  0
roll = "yes"
answer = "no"

import time
import random


input("Roll the dice?")
while roll == "yes" or roll =="y":
     print("Rolling...")
     dice1 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print(dice1)
     time.sleep(1)


     dice2 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print (dice2)
     time.sleep(1)


     total1 = dice1 + dice2
     score = (score + total1)
     if total1 == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11:
         score = (score +5)
     else:
          total1 == 2 or 4 or 6 or  8 or 10 or 12
          score = (score +10)
          print("Your score is", score)
```

I didn't get any error messages. What should happen is for the rolling to only occur twice.

Comment: As you never modify `roll` in your while loop, it will always be “yes” so the while loop will carry on forever. BTW your calculations/tests `total1==1 or 4 or...` and `total1==2 or 4 or...` is complete nonsensical code. Try printing total1 and you will see it is always `True`.

Comment: Read more about how not to use `if` like your code does here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581073/two-different-ways-of-writing-the-if-statement-why-the-second-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck in an infinite loop. The value of roll will always be "yes" which is the condition you check for. You then never change the value of "roll". SO the loop will keep on going. Try adding a variable assignment to input and provide a means of breaking out of the while loop in your conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

`input("roll the dice")` will not do anything. Try this:

```py
min = 1
max = 6
score =  0
roll = "yes"
answer = "no"

import time
import random


while roll == "yes" or roll =="y":
     print("Rolling...")
     dice1 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print(dice1)
     time.sleep(1)


     dice2 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print (dice2)
     time.sleep(1)


     total1 = dice1 + dice2
     score = (score + total1)
     if total1 == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11:
         score = (score +5)
     else:
          total1 == 2 or 4 or 6 or  8 or 10 or 12


     total1 = dice1 + dice2
     score = (score + total1)
     if total1 == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11:
         score = (score +5)
     else:
          total1 == 2 or 4 or 6 or  8 or 10 or 12
          score = (score +10)
     print("Your score is", score)
     roll = input("Roll the dice?")
```

When you assigned value `"yes"` to `roll`, you never change it afterwards. So the while loop goes on forever.

This code works for me.

**OUTPUT**

```py
============================= RESTART: D:\example.py =============================
Rolling...
2
3
Your score is 20
Roll the dice?y
Rolling...
5
6
Your score is 52
Roll the dice?yes
Rolling...
2
5
Your score is 76
Roll the dice?no
>>>
```

Comment: It's still looping

Comment: Now it rolls once then asks roll the dice? then if i say yes it does it again and then asks again and again but it doesn't print the score.

Comment: @AspaeringStar7 I have updated answer with output. Is that what you expect?